# Characterization of uncountable set

Tags: general-topology, analysis, logic, set-theory

I was looking at this question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/132286/proving-a-set-is-uncountable) and was wondering, if also the opposite direction holds. Specifically, I want to prove/disprove the statement: a set $A$ is uncountable, if and only if there exists an injective function $f:(0,1) \to A$.

Comment: Is this not the heart of the Continuum Hypothesis?  If we had a set with cardinality between that of the integers and that of the real numbers, it would fail to admit such an injection.

Comment: @Lulu Yes, indeed. But I did not know of the CH. Thanks for pointing it. So, the answer is "we do not know"?

Comment: Not quite ....it is known that the Continuum Hypothesis is undecidable.  More precisely, it is independent of the "standard" axioms of set theory.

Comment: @Lulu. Ok, thank you! I got it. But to set it clear: Since, assuming that the hypothesis is true or that its negation is true does not affect any other statement, can I just say in an exercise that I have: "I assume that the CH holds, so I have such an $f$..." and then proceed with the solution of the exercise?

Comment: Well, that's the nature of independence. If, as most do, you accept [ZFC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zermelo%E2%80%93Fraenkel_set_theory_) as the standard axiom set for set theory then you are free to add either the axiom that no set exists between $\mathbb Z$ and $\mathbb R$ or you are free to add the axiom that there is such a set.  One extended axiom set is internally consistent if and only if the other is.  The Parallel Postulate sits in a similar relation to the other axioms of Planar Geometry.

Comment: I should say: I am no kind of set theorist.  I expect that others could give you more color on the issue.

Comment: @Lulu. Ok, thanks a lot for your great help!

Comment: In particular, the least uncountable ordinal (the set of all countable ordinals) would be an exception, if there are any exceptions at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The statement "Every uncountable set admits an injection from $(0, 1)$" is the **continuum hypothesis** (C); it is known that CH is independent from the ZFC axioms, meaning that ZFC can neither prove nor disprove CH.

However, it is *not* true that "assuming that the hypothesis is true or that its negation is true does not affect any other statement:" CH does interact with other independent sentences. For instance, [Freiling's axiom of symmetry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freiling%27s_axiom_of_symmetry) is an arguably-reasonable principle which is equivalent to the *negation* of CH: if one is true, the other is false. On the other hand, [certain natural combinatorial principles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diamond_principle) or [statements saying that all sets are "reasonably definable" in a certain sense](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_constructibility) *imply* CH

There is a huge variety of statements independent of ZFC which interact with each other in really interesting ways; indeed, one of the main consequences of the discover of forcing was the realization that beyond a certain point, set-theoretic questions are arguably more frequently undecidable-from-ZFC than decidable-from-ZFC; this led to a push towards discovery strong hypotheses which, when added as axioms, would resolve large classes of questions. These include:

- The axiom of constructibility (linked above).
- [Large cardinal hypotheses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Large_cardinal), which imply that reasonably definable sets of real numbers have nice properties; also their [generic versions](https://eudml.org/doc/231091), which resolve combinatorial principles about the continuum (unlike large cardinals themselves).
- [Forcing axioms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proper_forcing_axiom), which resolve combinatorial questions about the continuum (and imply the negation of CH!).

If you're interested in the search for new axioms of set theory, [this is a great paper to read](http://isites.harvard.edu/fs/docs/icb.topic882819.files/FST_1.pdf).

Comment: The link to `isites.harvard.edu` is broken. I'm also unable to find any copy saved on the Wayback Machine.